# A single function for select query in a project its execution or loading time is fast or slow

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, performance, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter project.

1. I am making a "common_model" php page in codeignite project-->application->models and using a method(getSingleRow) for select only a row from tables(any table just like student, users,admin,employee).
   ex.

   ```
   public function getSingleRow($table_name,$where){

       $this->db->where($where);
       $query = $this->db->get($table_name);
       return $query->row();    
   }
   $where is using for columns where condition data.
   ```
2. I have second project=>student,users,admin,employee section in my project.
   every section i am making different model page and different method for select query.
   ex. For student 
   application->models->student_model php page and method is this.

   ```
   public function getStudentSingleRow($where){
       $this->db->where($where);
       $query = $this->db->get('student_table');
       return $query->row();  
   }
   ```

and just like using for all section(admin,users,employee) for model page and method.

My question is which coding functionality is working faster first(1) or second(2)?

if i have 1100k users 50k employees and 100k students in different tables and more tables.
i am using mysql server.

Comment: How does it matter ? In first case, just ensure that your *generalized* model class is **robust** enough to handle any table case.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is the marginally small amount of memory you use when passing and storing the variable `table_name` otherwise the two are functionally and speed wise the same.

Also `$this->db->where->($where);` should be `$this->db->where($where);`.

As a matter of course I would stray away from the first approach as it is less maintainable is a specific table schema changes. Better to introduce a model for each `student`, `admin`, .etc.